# Sending a string using a protocol buffer message

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, message, solace

How to send string as protocol buffer message? I want to do the following:

```
Message message1 = "some string"
ByteString data1 = (message1).toByteString();
System.out.println(String.format("Publishing [%s] on subject [%s]", message1, subject));
streamHandler1.publish(subject, data1);
```

Comment: You need an actual protocol buffer message type of your own that contains a string field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use protocol buffer to serialize your object into a byte array.

Then, send the byte array to a Solace appliance/VMR as part of a [BytesMessage](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/API__Developer_Online_Reference_Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/BytesMessage.html)

There's a simple example of how to send a message at the [Solace website](http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/java-tutorials/publish-subscribe_java/).
Note that the example makes use of `TextMessage`, but can be easily replaced with `BytesMessage`.

In sequence:

1. Connect to the Solace Message Router
2. Create a producer
3. Create the `BytesMessage` object
4. Serialize your protocol buffer into a byte array
5. Attach the byte array to the previously created `BytesMessage`
6. Send the message